# Change your language in Multilungal site of share point 2013 (on premises)

Tags: sharepoint-server, alternate-language

how to change your language setting in multilungal site of sharepoint 2013 (On-Premises).

kindly do the needful

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First go to site settings-> language settings, specify which alternate languages the site will support.  Make sure you have other language packages installed in SharePoint server.

Then change your personal language settings in mysite: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/change-your-personal-language-and-region-settings-caa1fccc-bcdb-42f3-9e5b-45957647ffd7

Comment: plz check this link : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/9c832f55-7eda-4173-bd2a-b59aa03fbeb1/failed-to-run-sharepoint-products-configuration-wizard?forum=winserverpowershell